# multiple threads-not able to access class member variables set by constructor

Tags: c++

I am spawning threads from one of the functions called by main. 
The start routine of this thread is a function in another separate class altogether. So to get access to that class, i have written an extern "C" function, by which i am able to call the start routine.
But the problem is, after getting to the start routine, the thread is not able to access the member variables value set by the constructor of the Class.

This seems strange to me as everything is perfect when i am running the code without using threads.
Can someone please suggest me what would be going wrong?

I am posting some relevant code details below:

`extern "C"{

```
void* run(void* arg)
{
    CFileOp* trans = static_cast<CFileOp*>(arg);
    trans->write_block(arg);
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
int
TestFileOps(int file_size, CGlobalItems &globals){
...

for(i = 0; i < num_chunks; i++)
{
pthread_create( &thread_id[i], NULL, run, buf);
}

...
}`
```

//there is a class CFileOp which has some private member variables and write_block is a public function of it.

```
void* CFileOp::write_block(PVOID buf)
{
int rc = my_write(78, buf, m_chunk_size);
 if(rc != m_chunk_size)
 {
   fprintf(stderr, "Can't write block; rc=%d, buf=%p, chunk_size=%d\n", rc, buf, m_chunk_size);
    pthread_exit((void *)-1);return 0;;
  }
m_cur_pos++;
fprintf(stderr,"m_cur_pos: %d   m_chunks_per_file: %d\t",m_cur_pos,m_chunks_per_file);
  if(m_cur_pos >= m_chunks_per_file)                                                    
  {
   if(seek(0, SEEK_CUR) == -1)
    pthread_exit((void *)-1);return 0;// return -1;
 }
pthread_exit((void *)rc);
return 0;
}
```

I can't post the whole code as its a benchmark code and is very long and detailed. 
Please help.

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to start threads and pass parameters to them. Which one did you use?

Comment: Is that variable marked volatile?

Comment: Threads have nothing to do with visibilty of class members.  Do you call the thread function if you don't use threads?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly you want to call a member function from a thread, you can just do if you have c++11

```
 std::thread th(&my_class::my_mem_func, &my_object);
```

this will create a thread `th` and execute the `my_mem_func` of `my_object`

EDIT

```
std::thread th(&my_writer::write_some, &writer_object, data);
th.join();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Actually, i am using pthread_create() API to create a thread. I am passing the following function as a start routine to the thread which is created by pthread_create()

extern "C"
{
void* run(void* arg)
    {
        CFileOp* trans = static_cast<CFileOp*>(arg);
        trans->write_block(arg);
        return 0;
    }
}
run() is then calling write_block() method which belongs to some other class.
The problem is that the thread is able to get to the write_block() method but isn't able to access the values of member variables of that class.

Please help

Comment: @sam32 your going to have to post code, do you have to use pthreads, std::threads are standards compliant and cross platform, I can't really help you with pthreads. either way we still need to see a CONCISE code example/

Comment: As I said I really can't help you that much with pthreads but if you want to give std::threads a try I'll put the method of doing that in my answer.

Comment: ok.. I would give std::threads a try.
It would be great if you can explain me the usage of std::threads with an example that would be relevant to my problem.

Thanks for your help ! I appreciate that.

Comment: Ok, but I don't really understand exactly what your code is supposed to do. If you could explain that to me I will gladly help

Comment: I am calling a function TestFileOps() from main(). This function is supposed to spawn "num_chunks" number of threads. Each thread is suppose to call CFileOp::write_block method of class CFileOp. 

When i am doing so, i am getting a segmentation fault when the thread is calling my_write which is another member function of class CFileOp. The thread is not able to access m_chunk_size, which is a member variable of class CFileOp

Comment: @sam32 no I mean, what are you trying to do with the threads, is there some sort of file operation going on here,

Comment: Actually i am modifying a file benchmark(bonnie++). I am writing wrappers for read,write,open,close calls. I have done this but now to improve performance i got to make it multi threaded.

Comment: I don't really understand that, why do you need thread to do that, threads often make things slow, for example there is a big overhead in spawning a new thread. Are you writing to the same file in multiple threads

Comment: yes i have to write to the same file using multiple threads but to random blocks locations in the file and not sequentially.